# Split Python Flask app into multiple files

Tags: python, web-services, file-organization, flask

I'm having trouble understanding how to split a flask app into multiple files.

I'm creating a web service and I want to split the api's into different files (AccountAPI.py, UploadAPI.py, ...), just so I don't have one huge python file.

I've read that you can do this with Blueprints, but I'm not entirely sure that route is the right one for me.

Ultimately I want to run one Main python file and include other files so that when it runs, they are considered one big file.

For example if I have Main.py and AccountAPI.py I want to be able to do this:

Main.py:

```
from flask import Flask
import AccountAPI

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

AccountAPI.py:

```
@app.route("/account")
def accountList():
    return "list of accounts"
```

I know with this example it obviously won't work, but is it possible to do something like that?

Thanks

Comment: I found that many StackOverflow pages and other sites have solutions demanding the use of a blueprint. It's not necessary. A regular Python module will do.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Yes, Blueprints are the right way to do it. What you are trying to do can be achieved like this:

Main.py

```
from flask import Flask
from AccountAPI import account_api

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(account_api)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

AccountAPI.py

```
from flask import Blueprint

account_api = Blueprint('account_api', __name__)

@account_api.route("/account")
def accountList():
    return "list of accounts"
```

If this is an option, you might consider using different URL prefixes for the different APIs/Blueprints in order to cleanly separate them. This can be done with a slight modification to the above `register_blueprint` call:

```
app.register_blueprint(account_api, url_prefix='/accounts')
```

For further documentation, you may also have a look at [the official docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/).

Comment: This worked perfectly for me thanks! I guess I should have read the Blueprint docs more carefeully.

Comment: Hey, I have a question. In following above code, does url for accountList() be matched 'domain/accounts/account'?

Comment: Can Main.py and AccountAPI.py have a shared global variable that is in either of the files?

Comment: Is there a simple solution for putting `accountList` inside a class in the same file?

Comment: Worked like a charm, further how to add protected end point by using JWT in separate .py files

Comment: @AshokSri This goes beyond the scope of the question. I would recommend to search for a good tutorial on Flask and JWT.

Answer (score 55):

Using `Blueprint` you can add your routes in the `routes` directory.

#### Structure

```
app.py
routes
    __init__.py
    index.py
    users.py
```

#### __init__.py

```
from flask import Blueprint
routes = Blueprint('routes', __name__)

from .index import *
from .users import *
```

#### index.py

```
from flask import render_template
from . import routes

@routes.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

#### users.py

```
from flask import render_template
from . import routes

@routes.route('/users')
def users():
    return render_template('users.html')
```

#### app.py

```
from routes import *
app.register_blueprint(routes)
```

---

If you want to add a new route file, say `accounts.py`, you just need to create the file `accounts.py` in the `routes` directory, just like `index.py` and `users.py`, then import it in the `routes.__init__.py` file

```
from .accounts import *
```

Comment: It's throwing an Import Error

Comment: Importing in middle of the file can be considered as bad practice?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using blueprints and want to route / redirect to a url of your blueprint inside a template you are using you need to use the correct url_for statement.

In your case if you would like to open the url account of your blueprint you have to state it like this in your **template**:

```
href="{{ url_for('account_api.account') }}"
```

and for the main **app** it would look like this:

```
redirect(url_for('account_api.account'))
```

Otherwise the werkzeug library will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

One another way to do this can be with [lazy loading](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/lazyloading/), where you would explicitly attach view functions on need basis.