# Split Python Flask-Menu app into multiple files

Tags: python, flask

As an extension of this question [Split Python Flask app into multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231359/split-python-flask-app-into-multiple-files)

I want to use [Flask-Menu](http://flask-menu.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and have each separate menu page in it's own Python file.

Here is my main site `main.py` file this has the `/first` menu item

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Blueprint, abort
from flask_wtf import Form
from flask.ext import menu

from wtforms import HiddenField

from second import bp_second

class EmptyForm(Form):
    hidden_field = HiddenField('You cannot see this', description='Nope')

def create_app(configfile=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(bp_second)
    menu.Menu(app=app)

    @app.route('/')
    @menu.register_menu(app, '.', 'Home')
    def index():
        form = EmptyForm()
        form.validate_on_submit()
        return render_template('index.html', form=form)

    @app.route('/first')
    @menu.register_menu(app, '.first', 'First', order=0)
    def first():
        form = EmptyForm()
        form.validate_on_submit()
        return render_template('index.html', form=form)

    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_app().run(debug=True)
```

I have a menu item called `second.py` here this has the `/second` menu item

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from flask_wtf import Form
from flask.ext import menu

from wtforms import TextField

class TextForm(Form):
    text = TextField(u'text', [validators.Length(min=2, max=5, message="my item")])

bp_second = Blueprint('second', __name__, url_prefix='/second')

@bp_second.route("/second")
@menu.register_menu(bp_second, '.second', 'Second', order=1)
def second():
    form = TickerForm()
    form.validate_on_submit() #to get error messages to the browser
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

How ever when I click the menu item for `/second` I get a `"GET /meta HTTP/1.1" 404 -` message. The `/` and `/first` menu items work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect, that your route is wrong. As I read it your route for **second** is /second/second so your menu entry should be

```
@menu.register_menu(bp_second, '.second.second', 'Second', order=1)
```

You can check the Flask-Menu documentation about [Blueprints Support in Flask-Menu](http://flask-menu.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#blueprint-support)