# Flask route from different file is not working

Tags: python, rest, flask, routes

I started building an application based on Flask. The idea is to play a little with REST API, without any HTML etc., just simple JSON responses.

Everything seems to work if I have everything in one file.

```
 tasks = [  # pylint: disable=C0103
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': 'First',
        'content': u'First task'
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': 'Second',
        'content': u'Second task'
    }
]
app = Flask(__name__)   

@app.route('/api/v1.0/tasks/', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    """
    [GET] Retrieves all tasks
    """
    return jsonify({'tasks': tasks})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This works perfectly when I run my flask app. The problem is starting when I want to move it to other file. I just moved *get_tasks* method to /my_app/views.py and declaration *app = Flask(**name**)* into my_app/**init**.py. Of course I added import in my main app.py file. Server starts normally, but I am not able to get result. When I move back the method to app.py, it works. What am I missing here?

EDIT

app.py

```
from my_app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

views.py

```
from flask import jsonify
from my_app import app
@app.route('/api/v1.0/tasks/', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    """
    [GET] Retrieves all tasks
    """
    tasks = [  # pylint: disable=C0103
        {
            'id': 1,
            'title': 'First',
            'content': u'First task'
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'title': 'Second',
            'content': u'Second task'
        }
    ]
    return jsonify({'tasks': tasks})
```

dir structure:

```
project_name/
--- my_app/
----- __init__.py
----- views.py
--- app.py
```

---

EDIT 2
As I mentioned in comment, I moved everything from **init**.py into app.py file, and it still don't work, but when I've added in app.py one extra import, after app = Flask(**name**), it works. Import is

```
from my_app import views
```

When I am trying to add this import before, I have circular import

Comment: can you show us the code for the new app.py, and the directory structure, what you are saying should work, also if __name__ == '__main__':  if __name__ == '__main__': should only be one if __name__ I assume thats a copy paste error

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: don't know why someone downvoted, looks like a legit question.
Anyway, I wouldn't put anythin in the __init__.py file, change app.py to contain:
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
    and let's see what happens next (I would also change the import)

Comment: I moved everything from __init__.py as you suggested to my app.py, and it still don't work, however when I added "from my_app import views" in app.py after creation of app object, it works...of course I can't add this import before, cause I have circular import...how to solve it?

Comment: Wait, this is still unanswered?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231359/split-python-flask-app-into-multiple-files

This fixed it for me.